# Determine application first run

Tags: android

I want to determine whether my application being run for the first time, and so it will be hard to pass around it.

The preferences or empty file approaches are not going to work because you can simply clear the application data or delete the empty file.

Also I want to do it offline so no server checking is going to work either.

Maybe it's possible to add some code to the installation of the apk so it will only run once.

So my best bet is spawning a lot of empty files all around and hope the user won't find them, but this is pretty messy.

Has anyone ever done this somehow before? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The preferences or empty file approaches are not going to work because you can simply clear the application data or delete the empty file.

One possibility is to have a `BroadcastReceiver`, registered in your manifest, that you do not actually use for anything. On first run of your app, disable that receiver via `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()`. On future runs, you can determine if that `BroadcastReceiver` is already disabled via `PackageManager` and `getReceiverInfo()`.

If the user uninstalls and reinstalls the app, the app will return to its original state. Rooted device users can also get past this. Otherwise, this should be reasonably solid.

Comment: It is  a nice a solution but if the user updates the app, then it will also return to its orginal state.  If thats ok with the asker, then a global static variables can be used to achieve the same thing. No?

Comment: @Snake: "It is a nice a solution but if the user updates the app, then it will also return to its orginal state" -- I'm not certain about that, though it's a possibility. I would expect that if the component is named the same, that the enabled/disabled status would persist past an upgrade. It would definitely need to be tested. "then a global static variables can be used to achieve the same thing. No?" -- no, because static data members get cleared when the process is terminated, which happens all of the time. The enabled/disabled setting is persistent.

Comment: So is it safe to say that this way you can store info without anyone to see it? (by creating receivers and using them as bits)

Comment: @Vladp: Anyone who wants to can see it. Whether or not a receiver is enabled is visible to all applications who choose to rummage through `PackageManager`.

Comment: This is fine as long as they can't change it. So is there any way other application or the user will change the receiver state?

Comment: @Vladp: Again, rooted device users can probably change this, and uninstalling/reinstalling the app will return you to the original state.

Answer (score -1):

I know you said you dont want files, but if you create them as local internal storage then the user can not delete them as they wont have access unless it is rooted phone. Clearing data "may" delete them.

There is another solution but it is lengthy one. Use SQLite database.IT is local and I dont think it can be deleted otherwise the whole application will crash

Comment: A SQLite database is a file. It will be deleted when the user clears data (internal storage) or via any file manager (external storage).

Comment: @CommonsWare, absolutely. I didn't know that, I just tried it and indeed it deletes it. Thanks for the info